# Sum coefficients equivalent the expression Change of index

Tags: calculus

I try to get new expresion from other but I do not how to change the index in
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, c(n) \sum _{k=0}^n \sum _{m=k+1}^n b(k) a(n,m)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } d(n) \sum _{k=0}^n b(k) a(n,k)$$
Thanks anyway

Comment: On the left hand side you have $c(n)$, yet on the right there's $d(n)$. Is it a typo or some functions which definition you didn't include?

Comment: are numbers in general raised to different powers it was to unfold the sum of the left and make it of the right type thanks Lee David

Comment: What about the functional form of $a(x,y)$? Clearly $b(x)$ can be whatever, but is $a(x,y)$ also just a single term raised to some power, or is it just any real-valued function? You should really included these information (known constraints on $a$ to $d$) in the post. Please click on the "edit" and update your question to make the post comprehensible. You cannot expect other people to read through the conversation (the comments) between you and I.